# What does the "[0][0]" of the layers connected to in keras model.summary mean?

Tags: keras, keras-layer

As is depicted in the following table, what does the `[0][0]` of the `input_1[0][0]` mean?

```
__________________________________________________
Layer (type)          Output Shape  Param # Connected to           
===================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)  (None, 1)     0                              
___________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)   (None, 1)     0       input_1[0][0]          
___________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)   (None, 1)     0       input_1[0][0]          
===================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
___________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That's a good question, however to answer it we must dive into the internals of how layers are connected to each other in Keras. So let's start:

**0) What is a tensor?**

A tensor is a data structure that represent data and they are basically n-dimensional arrays. All the data and information passed between layers must be tensors.

**1) What is a layer?**

In the simplest sense, a layer is a computation unit where it gets one or more **input tensors**, then applies a set of operations (e.g. multiplication, addition, etc.) on them, and gives the result as one or more **output tensors**. When you apply a layer on some input tensors, under the hood a **Node** is created.

**2) So what is a Node?**

To represent the connectivity between two layers, Keras internally uses an object of [`Node`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/994c4bb338ce440a27df5db48b8f5044a3e8f611/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L1178) class. When a layer is applied on some new input, a node is created and is added to the `_inbound_nodes` property of that layer. Further, when the output of a layer is used by another layer, a new node is created and is added to `_outbound_nodes` property of that layer. So essentially, this data structure lets Keras to find out how layers are connected to each other using the following properties of an object of type `Node`:

- `input_tensors`: it is a list containing the input tensors of the node.
- `output_tensors`: it is a list containing the output tensors of the node.
- `inbound_layers`: it is a list which contains the layers where the `input_tensors` come from.
- `outbound_layers`: the consumer layers, i.e. the layers that takes `input_tensors` and turns them into `output_tensors`.
- `node_indices`: it is a list of integers which contains the node indices of `input_tensors` (would explain this more in the answer to the following question).
- `tensor_indices`: it is a list of integers which contains the indices of `input_tensors` within their corresponding inbound layer (would explain this more in the answer to the following question).

**3) Fine! Now tell me what those values in "Connected to" column of model summary mean?**

To better understand this, let's create a simple model. First, let's create two input layers:

```py
inp1 = Input((10,))
inp2 = Input((20,))
```

Next, we create a `Lambda` layer that has two output tensors, the first output is the input tensor divided by 2, and the second output is the input tensor multiplied by 2:

```py
lmb_layer = Lambda(lambda x: [x/2, x*2])
```

Let's apply this lambda layer on `inp1` and `inp2`:

```py
a1, b1 = lmb_layer(inp1)
a2, b2 = lmb_layer(inp2)
```

After doing this, two nodes have been created and added to `_inbound_nodes` property of `lmb_layer`:

```py
>>> lmb_layer._inbound_nodes
[<keras.engine.base_layer.Node at 0x7efb9a105588>,
 <keras.engine.base_layer.Node at 0x7efb9a105f60>]
```

The first node corresponds to the connectivity of the `lmb_layer` with the first input layer (`inp1`) and the second node corresponds to the connectivity of this layer with the second input layer (`inp2`). Further, each of those nodes have two output tensors (corresponding to `a1`,`b1` and `a2`,`b2`):

```py
>>> lmb_layer._inbound_nodes[0].output_tensors
[<tf.Tensor 'lambda_1/truediv:0' shape=(?, 10) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'lambda_1/mul:0' shape=(?, 10) dtype=float32>]

>>> lmb_layer._inbound_nodes[1].output_tensors
[<tf.Tensor 'lambda_1_1/truediv:0' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'lambda_1_1/mul:0' shape=(?, 20) dtype=float32>]
```

Now, let's create and apply four different `Dense` layers and apply them on the four output tensors we obtained:

```py
d1 = Dense(10)(a1)
d2 = Dense(20)(b1)
d3 = Dense(30)(a2)
d4 = Dense(40)(b2)

model = Model(inputs=[inp1, inp2], outputs=[d1, d2, d3, d4])
model.summary()
```

The model summary would look like this:

```py
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 10)           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            (None, 20)           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)               multiple             0           input_1[0][0]                    
                                                                 input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 10)           110         lambda_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 20)           220         lambda_1[0][1]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 30)           630         lambda_1[1][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 40)           840         lambda_1[1][1]                   
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,800
Trainable params: 1,800
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

In the "Connected to" column for a layer the values have a format of: `layer_name[x][y]`. The `layer_name` corresponds to the layer where the input tensors of the this layer comes from. For example, all the `Dense` layers are connected to `lmb_layer` and therefore get their inputs from this layer. The `[x][y]` corresponds to the node index (i.e. `node_indices`) and tensor index (i.e. `tensor_indices`) of the the input tensors, respectively. For example:

- The `dense_1` layer is applied on `a1` which is the first (i.e. index: 0) output tensor of the first (i.e. index: 0) inbound node of `lmb_layer`, therefore the connectivity is displayed as: `lambda_1[0][0]`.
- The `dense_2` layer is applied on `b1` which is the second (i.e. index: 1) output tensor of the first (i.e. index: 0) inbound node of `lmb_layer`, therefore the connectivity is displayed as: `lambda_1[0][1]`.
- The `dense_3` layer is applied on `a2` which is the first (i.e. index: 0) output tensor of the second (i.e. index: 1) inbound node of `lmb_layer`, therefore the connectivity is displayed as: `lambda_1[1][0]`.
- The `dense_4` layer is applied on `b2` which is the second (i.e. index: 1) output tensor of the first (i.e. index: 1) inbound node of `lmb_layer`, therefore the connectivity is displayed as: `lambda_1[1][1]`.

---

That's it! If you want to know more how `summary` method works, you can take a look at the [`print_summary`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/d954aef2a2e33532f8725f58183cf605f5c54656/keras/utils/layer_utils.py#L24) function. And if you want to find out how the connections are printed, you can take a look at the [`print_layer_summary_with_connections`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/d954aef2a2e33532f8725f58183cf605f5c54656/keras/utils/layer_utils.py#L121) function.