# How to insert a new input layer into a pretrained Keras CNN model, and remove all layers before the new input layer?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

For a pre-trained CNN model in Keras, how to insert a new input layer into hidden layers and remove the layers before the new input layer? For instance, VGG16 is a pre-trained model in Keras and I want to remove the first two layers (input_1 and block1_conv1 layer) and give the rest model a new input layer. The shape is of the input is (None, 224, 224, 64) and original input is (None, 224, 224, 3).

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
model = VGG16(include_top=True, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=None, pooling=None, classes=1000)
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a Keras model, with a non-sequential architecture like ResNet, into sub-models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56147685/how-to-split-a-keras-model-with-a-non-sequential-architecture-like-resnet-into)

Comment: The above solution works for both sequential (e.g. VGG16) and non-sequential models (e.g. ResNet).